# parse text with sed + awk + bash

Tags: awk, sed

I need a hint regarding the text parsing via sed , awk or bash:

**example text:**

```
VRF MediaPlayer
192.168.1.1  52466  5w12d
192.168.1.2  52467  3w1d


VRF Telecom
10.10.1.1   43432  1d1h
12.20.1.1   23211  23w1d
30.30.22.1  43211  14w22d
```

**Expected output:**

```
192.168.1.1  52466  5w12d  MediaPlayer
192.168.1.2  52467  3w1d   MediaPlayer


10.10.1.1   43432  1d1h    Telecom
12.20.1.1   23211  23w1d   Telecom
30.30.22.1  43211  14w22d  Telecom
```

How can I put VRF "Name" as 4th column, what syntax should I use?

Regards,

Answer (score 4):

```
awk '/^VRF /{vrf=$2}/^[0-9]/{print$0,vrf}' | column -t
```

or pure `awk`:

```
awk '/^VRF /{vrf=$2} /^[0-9]/{printf("% -30s %s\n",$0,vrf)}'
```

Comment: @OP: `/^([0-9]|$)/{print $0,(NF>0)?vrf:""}` if you need to preserve the blank records

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '/^VRF/{vrf=$2; next} {print $0 (NF ? OFS vrf : "")}' file
192.168.1.1  52466  5w12d MediaPlayer
192.168.1.2  52467  3w1d MediaPlayer


10.10.1.1   43432  1d1h Telecom
12.20.1.1   23211  23w1d Telecom
30.30.22.1  43211  14w22d Telecom
```

Answer (score 0):

With sed

```
sed '/VRF /{s///;h;:A;N;s/.*\n//;/^$/!{G;s/\n/ /;p;bA}}' infile
```

If the line not contain 'VRF ' print

Else substitute with nothing so the line = MediaPlayer for example

and copy in the holdspace 'h'

:A is for the loop

Get a newline N and remove the previous line s/.*\n//

If the line is not empty, copy the hold space ('MediaPlayer') at the end of the pattern space 'G'

Remove the \n ,print the line and return to :A

Answer (score 0):

a simple **awk** solution

```
$ awk '/^VRF/{a=$NF; next} NF{$0=$0 FS a}1 ' file
192.168.1.1  52466  5w12d MediaPlayer
192.168.1.2  52467  3w1d MediaPlayer


10.10.1.1   43432  1d1h Telecom
12.20.1.1   23211  23w1d Telecom
30.30.22.1  43211  14w22d Telecom
```

`/^VRF/{a=$NF; next}` : If record starts with VRF then set variable `a` with the last field in that record. Then `next` and do nothing

`NF{$0=$0 FS a}1` : If `NF` then line has some fields and is not empty then simply append `a` to the record and print it. If it's empty don't append and simply print.